How do I delete instances that overlap?
I'd like only one overlapping instance to be deleted.


thanks in advance

You can try merging the points by distance before instancing the cubes

@Gorgious if merge by distance, the cubes are not aligned along the curve

Transfer the rotation to the new points ?
